# How to create a multiple insert query using Angular and Laravel 5.2

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I want create a multiple insert query into 4 different table using Laravel 5.2 and Angular.

I have design my RESTApi with Laravel and tested with Postman, and it is working 100% fine, but I can seem to fathom how to use Angular to POST my data to other table in my database. Only one table seems to be updated with my records, all other tables are left blank.

```
public function createSnrStudents(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    $student = SeniorStudent::create($input);

    $lastInsertID = $student->senior_students_id;
    $session = $request['session'];
    $subject1 = $request['subject1'];
    $subject2 = $request['subject2'];
    $subject3 = $request['subject3'];
    $subject4 = $request['subject4'];
    $subject5 = $request['subject5'];
    $subject6 = $request['subject6'];
    $subject7 = $request['subject7'];
    $subject8 = $request['subject8'];
    $subject9 = $request['subject9'];
    $subject10 = $request['subject10'];

    $timestamp = Carbon::now('UTC')->toDateTimeString();
    //$results = SnrStudentsR1::create(['senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session,
      //  'subject'=>$subject1]);

    $insert = array(
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject1, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject2, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject3, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject4, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject5, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject6, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject7, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject8, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject9, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp),
        array('senior_students_id'=>$lastInsertID, 'session'=>$session, 'subject'=>$subject10, 'created_at'=>$timestamp, 'updated_at'=>$timestamp)
    );


    $results= DB::table('snr_students_r1s')->insert($insert);
    $results2 = DB::table('snr_students_r2s')->insert($insert);
    $results3 = DB::table('snr_students_r3s')->insert($insert);

    return response()->json(array(
        'students'=> $student,
        'results1' => $results,
        'results2' => $results2,
        'results3' => $results3,
    ));
}
```

Here is my Angular to that i intend to use to POST data to my database containing the different table.

```
controller: function ($http, $scope) {
                $scope.createSnrStudent = function () {
                    var log = this;
                    log.SnrStudent = false;
                    $http.post('api/createStudent', {
                        'firstname':$scope.firstname,
                        'lastname':$scope.lastname,
                        'middlename':$scope.middlename,
                        'regno':'2008',
                        'password': 'password',
                        'gender': $scope.gender,
                        'class': $scope.class,
                        'department': $scope.department,
                        'session': $scope.session,
                        'subject': 'MATHEMATICS',
                        'subject': 'ENGLISH',
                        'subject': 'FUTHER MATHEMATICS',
                        'subject': 'PHYSICS',
                        'subject': 'CHEMISTRY',
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        $http.post('api/createStudent',{

                        });
                        log.SnrStudent = true;
                        $scope.SnrStudent = 'Successful!!!';
                    }).error(function (error) {
                        log.SnrStudent = true;
                        $scope.SnrStudent = 'Error!!!';
                    });
                }
```

Please I need guidance on how to accomplice this task effectively.

senior_table is updating successfully, then in other tables I am getting my last ID from senior table to other tables, but I can't get the subject parameter to be updated to db

Comment: Please help with an answer. Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any error  in your response /

Comment: No error, only one table is updating with my data

Comment: Could you try using `try{..}catch{..}` block ? In catch block just add the exception variable to your json response and print the received response in browser console.

Comment: BTW, which table is getting updated among the above tables ?

Comment: Only the senior_students table is been updated with a students information.

Comment: senior_table is updating successfully, then in other tables I am getting my last ID from senior table to other tables, but I can't get the subject parameter to be updated to db